# How to get notified upon database updates in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

We host data in SQL Azure, we used to have query notifications if we host data on premise, how do we address it in case of SQL Azure? to get query notifications upon updates, inserts events other than keep polling from code?

Or is any other Azure services support this, e.g. mobile services? notification hubs? newbie to Azure offering here...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not aware of any native SQL Database functionality that performs this task.  Azure Automation (PowerShell-script-execution-as-a-service) would be a good candidate for this type of monitoring. It would, however, be pull (on a schedule) versus push.  For a reference Azure Automation runbook, please see the following: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-Automation-Your-SQL-30f8736b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger (special type of stored procedure) that is automatically executed after an insert happened. Documentation for triggers is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.120).aspx

As Joe states you will not be able to send an email out of SQL Database though.

Depending on how quick you need the notification after the insert, maybe you could make an insert into yet another table from within the trigger and pull the data as Joe says.